# How to us a permanent cookie in a before filter to filter for first time guests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a simple survey on my web page. 
I want to add a before_filter so that the same person can't take the survey more than once.

My idea is to

1) create and save a remember_token to each survey when it is submitted.

2) create a cookie based on that remember token to be placed on the submitter's browser

3) Every time some visits the page, use a before filter to make sure they don't have a cookie that matches a survey in the database.

I put together the below, but for some reason, it automatically redirects to the thanks_path, regardless of whether I have a remember token?

Why does it do this? Am I using the session cookie incorrectly?

My `surveys_controller` is as below

```
before_filter :new_visitor, only: [:new, :create]

def new
  #this is the survey form
  @survey = Survey.new
end

def create   
  #this submits the survey and creates a cookie on the client's browser
  @survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])
  if @survey.save
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = @survey.remember_token
    redirect_to thanks_path
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end

def thanks 
  #blank page that just says, "thanks for taking the survey!"
end

def new_visitor
  # if a browser has a survey cookie, redirect to thanks page
  unless Survey.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token]).nil?
    redirect_to thanks_path
  end    
end
```

I am creating the remember token in my `Survey` model.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :create_remember_token

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to test for the existence of the `cookie[:remember_token]` before using it as an argument to `find_by_remember_token()`. Only if `cookies[:remember_token]` is not nil and a record is found do you redirect to the thanks_page.

```
if cookies[:remember_token] && Survey.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    redirect_to thanks_page
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unless Survey.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token]).nil?
```

this means if Survey not nil then redirect, i think you need to change to

```
unless Survey.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
```

or

```
if Survey.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token]).nil?
```

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin. What I want to do is redirect `unless visitor is new to the site`. So I'm using `Survey.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token]).nil?` to mean `new to site.` Otherwise, do you think my logic makes sense?

Comment: What happens if the cookies[:remember_token] is nil? You are calling find_by with a nil argument. What is returned?

Comment: Thanks Fred. The problem seems to be that I was calling nil on the find_by argument as you say.